# HttpClient 4.x is there a way to set the 'maxTotalConnection' and 'defaultMaxPerRoute' while the instance is in use?

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using apache httpclient 4.x with [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html). Typically you create this as follows:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
        poolingConnManager.setMaxTotal(10);
        poolingConnManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
```

We are working on scenario wherein we need to set this configuration parameter when this instance is in use.

For example, if there is a need of more number of HTTP request to be handled. In such case, is it possible to change these values without affecting current operations.

Comment: you mean without restarting process/JVM?

Comment: Without  creating the instances again.

Comment: What is stopping you just setting those values on the connection manager whenever you deem fit?

Comment: Well, the question is, will those values take effect when the httpclient is already created. I am working to simulate the scenario. Will update this space.